# Is theory of equations a dead field today?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, soft-question, galois-theory

Is theory of equations a dead field today? By theory of equations I mean, specially, the study of polynomials and solving algebraic equations through radicals. There seem to be very few journals on such subjects. Also most of the great results are at least 100 years old, there are not many new results out there.

Any journals on that topics would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: Of course this field is not dead. It just has a different name after a long evolution: algebraic geometry / arithmetic geometry.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh, thank you sir. I did not know that they renamed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a [paper by Dummit](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X.pdf) from 1991 on solving solvable quintics, which fits into your desired topic. If you look at other papers that cite this one, you can find even more recent papers on related problems.